# Как в DataFrame обратиться к чётным значениям index?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Нужно изменить значения в столбце gauss_1 для тех строк, где четный индекс. Возможно ли использовать DataFrame.apply() или что-то другое лучше?
Пытаюсь что-то подобное соорудить:

```
df[['index', 'gauss_1']].apply(lambda x: pd.Series([x.index, None],axis=1), index=['index', 'gauss_1']) if (x.index % 2) == 0 else pd.Series([x.index, x.gauss_1], axis=1)
```

[image: DataFrame c заданными мной индексами]

Comment: пример исходных данных в вопросе должен быть в воспроизводимом виде, а не скриншотом.

Comment: учту на будущее

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно через `loc` и булев массив:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0, 10, 10), columns=['gauss_1'])
df.loc[df.index % 2 == 0, 'gauss_1'] = None
print(df)
```

Или с помощью метода `mask`:

```
df.gauss_1 = df.gauss_1.mask(df.index % 2 == 0)
print(df)
```

```
   gauss_1
0      NaN
1      7.0
2      NaN
3      4.0
4      NaN
5      8.0
6      NaN
7      5.0
8      NaN
9      2.0
```

Comment: Оба варианта рабочие. Спасибо!